# Create another Logon page for external link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I want to create another logon page for external direct link(multiple projects need identity Logon page appearance.)

Is that possible to create another view for logon controller or I need to create another controller? I tried to create another controller, but I can not access at all.

Is there someone get some good ideas about that??

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same authentication mechanism, you can just pass external URL as parameter

```
http://yourwebsite/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=<external url>
```

and then redirect the page to the return URL after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea for your logon to return to an external link. don't do that. See Ch7 of the Wrox Professional ASP.NET MVC 3 book.
This is known as an open redirect attack. There's code in ASP.NET MVC 3 internet template for the Account Controller which prevents Open Redirect, but the risk of allowing it is that anybody can give out links to your site's login address with a malicious url in the return url query string. By allowing this Open Redirect, you make your site's visitors prone to social engineering. A hacker could send out links to your site to your users. They click, it looks like your site, address bar is right, the site appears secure, cert good and all. They logon, then they're redirected by your site to an external url. The external url may have any code running at all, and could make your users vulnerable to any number of attacks/ javascript attacks.

I know I mention MVC in particular, but the same holds true for any site.

If you need a logon page for another site, then you need to copy in the controller and views to that project, as well as setting up the config in that project (you can view your existing project for the appropriate settings).

Are your sites all related, with the same users and such? or are they separate disparate sites? If they are all related, can you put them in one project? That way you could just use the one membership provider and db, and different controllers/view folders for the different sections of your site?

Or are you in a domain where you can use Windows Auth and skip showing a logon page?

Or do you want to go with a single sign on application like ACS in Azure or STS server, or something. (look for good/modern book on WIF, which discusses ACS 2.0, if so)